# Defining environment variables leads to Expected name=value pairs Error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to check whether `TIMEOUT` variable is set on the `Jenkinsfile`, if not set a default value in the `environment` section, but it is failing with below error.

What am I missing here ? Thanks.

```
Expected name=value pairs @ line xx, column x.
           environment {
           ^
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
@Library(['myshared@main']) _
Function_to_run{
    repo = 'Docker'
    NUM = 3
    NEXUS_URL = 'myorg/nexus'
    TIMEOUT = 30
}
```

Snippet from **function.groovy**

```
def call(body) {
    def params = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
     .....
     .....
      environment {
        NUM = ''
        PUSH_URL = "${NEXUS_URL}"
        REPO_ID = "${REPO_URL]}"
        if ("${params.TIMEOUT }") {
           timeout = "${params.TIMEOUT}"
        } else { def timeout  = 60;
         }
    }
}
```